# Use Multiple conditions in Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have implemented multiple conditions in case statement as below,

```
select officied from budgettable
where budgetid = case @budgetid when 7 then 7
                when 7 then  8
                when 7 then 10
                when 8 then 6
          end
```

but it didn't give me any result. If I pass budget-Id as `7` the query should return `8,10,7` budget id's.  Anything wrong in the above query?

Comment: What are you using the same conditions for all the `when`s?

Comment: Can you explain what your question should do? A case when in the where clause is kind of strange

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make when `@budgetId` is 7, then budgetId can be `IN (7, 8, 10)` - you can't do case statements like this.

Comment: @Kritner. you got the requirements. I have tried to put in the case statement but it gave me syntax error. so I eventually ended on this

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: @user5359841 . . . You should edit your question and specify what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you want something like this:

```
where budgetid = @budgetid or
      (@budgetid = 7 and budgetid in (7, 8, 10)) or
      (@budgetid = 8 and budgetid = 6)
```

Your query is failing because for all values of `@budgetid` other than 7 or 8, the `case` returns `NULL` -- which is treated as false.

Comment: It gave me some extra records in the output

Comment: @user5359841: You didn't explain your problem well and have given no sample data. This is why Gordon says he suspects that you want *something* like this. Gordon guessed that you want direct matches plus extra rules for @budgetid 7 and 8. If you don't want these, remove `budgetid = @budgetid or` from his query. Gordon's answer is the best you got, because as agim commented already "a case when in the where clause is kind of strange" when you have AND, OR and parentheses available.

Comment: @user5359841: Or *maybe* you want `where @budgetid not in (7,8) and budgetid = @budgetid) or (@budgetid = 7 ...`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner. Removing budgeted=@budgeted solves my problem. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the `case` as a boolean expression, returning `1` when your conditions are met:

```
select officied from budgettable
where 1 = case 
      when @budgetid = budgetid then 1
      when @budgetid = 7 and budgetid in (7,8,10) then 1 
      when @budgetid = 8 and budgetid in (6,8) then 1 
      end
```

This expands the results returned by `@budgetid` 7 to include 8 and 10.

Answer (score 2):

This is no answer. I just want to show how CASE WHEN works, so you see your mistake. Your query evaluates `case @budgetid`as follows:

1. when 7 then 7 => take a 7 for a @budgetid 7
2. when 7 then 8 => ignored, because we already said to take 7 for a @budgetid 7
3. when 7 then 10 => ignored, because we already said to take 7 for a @budgetid 7
4. when 8 then 6 => take a 6 for a @budgetid 8
5. end => no else here, so any other @budgetid results in NULL.

You then compare the result with `= budgetid`. This is never true for NULL. So you end up with:

```
where (@budgetid = 7 and budgetid = 7)
   or (@budgetid = 8 and budgetid = 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work !!

```
SELECT
    officied
FROM
    budgettable
WHERE
    1 = 1
AND
    1 = CASE
              WHEN
                @budgetid = budgetid THEN 1
              WHEN
                (@budgetid = 7 AND budgetid IN (7,8,10)) THEN 1
              WHEN
                (@budgetid = 8 AND budgetid IN (6,8) THEN) 1
          END
```

**Better solution :** Add a new column **is_budget_calculated** (Data type BIT) and update it as 0 and remaining as 1.